# Open only one page of report in Microsoft Access via VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

What I want to do is very simple, but I'm totally new to VBA. I want to open a report and filter it by page number, so that I could open, say, only page 2. I already have a variable for how many pages it is. I just need to know what to put in the filter argument of the `DoCmd.OpenReport` function.

The overall goal is to export each page as a separate PDF. If I can do the above, I can do the rest, but if there's something really simple I'm missing, I'm open to suggestions. Thanks.

This is Access 2010 by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print single pages you can work with the printer object ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff837177.aspx ) and the PrintOut command ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220516(v=office.11).aspx ), however, it seems likely that you have a natural break, such as a customer record, and these breaks can be used with the Where argument of OpenReport to easily get separate reports.

EDIT re comments

Very roughly:

```
sSQL = "SELECT SuitableField FROM Atable ORDER BY Something"

Set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset(sSQL)

Do While Not rs.EOF
   DoCmd.OpenReport "TheReport", acViewNormal, , _
       "SuitableField='" & rs!SuitableField & "'"
   rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

You may wish to do some work to ensure you are choosing reports with data in them.

Comment: Thanks! I thought about using PrintOut but I don't want the user to be prompted. Could you give me a little bit of detail about how to split by the first field? Assuming I know the first field but don't know what's in it?

Comment: @Drew What is the first field? What is the report based on - a query, a table, an SQL string?

Comment: I believe the first field is a string and the report is based on a query. I haven't done much with this database as this is only my third week at this job. I certainly wasn't there when the coding for this report is done. I can go back in this afternoon and do some reconnaissance; I'm not at work now.

Comment: What you need to do is loop through the recordset on which the report is based and use the where statement to print the report.

Comment: If you mean put a page break on the first field then when the report is in design view select View -> Sorting and Grouping.  Add the field you are interested in, set Group Footer to Yes.  Then add a page break in the report in this group footer.

Comment: @Chris The idea is to create separate PDFs, not simply a long report with page breaks.